# My .exe crashes as soon as I run it in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, crash, qt-creator

In Qt creator, I have an .exe that crashes as soon as I run the program. Debugging mode starts and stops immediately, displaying "Debugger started" and "Debugger stopped".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of missing the right *dll*s in the *exe* folder.

Add the respective debug or release  dlls on the exe folder (i.e debug/release folder where the .exe is created) and run the debug/run in Qt Creator.

To check what are the *dll*s missing, double click the .exe which is created by QtCreator.

Please verify whether it is a debug or release dll before adding it in the .exe path.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that all depending dlls of your executable are inside your PATH-variable or in the same folder of your executable. You can easily check which dlls are missing by opening your executable with depends ( you can get the tool here: [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).